# AlpineJS disable x-on:click if some condition happened

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

**My Issue:**
I want to disable the `x-on:click` on the `step = 1`.
So if you are on the website and are currently on `step = 1` the button wont work, it only works if `step = 2` gets triggered. Is something like that possible with AlpineJS?

**The code:**

```
<a href="#" x-on:click="step = 1, checkout = ! checkout">Clicking</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply attach the handler only if the step is > 1 with f.e. the logical AND operator:

```js
<a href="#" x-on:click="step > 1 && yourClickHandler()">Clicking</a>
```

In that case you should write a method `yourClickHandler` where you do the stuff you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy to read solution:

```
<a href="#" x-on:click="if (step > 1) yourClickHandler()">Clicking</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" x-on:click="step > 1 ? yourClickHandler() : anotherClickHandler()">Clicking</a>
```